# Zoom in to TensorBoard graphs using Chrome

Tags: python, keras, tensorboard

I tried using TensorBoard for the first time on a Python/Keras neural network regression program. It worked fine, but the "Graphs" output is so large it's too tiny to be readable in the window. Trying the usual "window drag" to zoom in resulted in the window moving around rather than zooming. I'm calling localhost:6006 in my Chrome browser. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling up/down with a mouse wheel will change the zoom. If you do not have a scroll-enabled mouse, there are tools for virtual scrolling with a keypress+drag (e.g. [Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/) on Mac).